# вывод столбцов из разных файлов друг за другом в ряд в Python

Tags: python

Нужно вывести столбцы из разных файлов друг за другом в ряд c подписями как в примере:

file 1

```
4 5    
4 6    
2 3
```

file 2

```
3 6
8 6
2 6
```

result file

```
#file 1 #file 2
4 5     3 6
4 6     8 6
2 3     2 6
```

Использую

```
            f.write("#")
            f.write(filename)
            f.write("\n")
            f.writelines(f1)
            f.write("\n")
```

но вывод получается один под другим

Comment: а зачем вам именно в ряд?

Comment: А где вы их читаете? Дополните код.

Answer (score 3):

[`open`](http://pythonz.net/references/named/open/) возвращает объект-[`итератор`](http://blog.swlogic.eu/2012/06/14/python-generators-cheatsheet/), передающий файл построчно.

[`zip`](http://pythonz.net/references/named/zip/) возвращает итератор по кортежам, где `i`-тый кортеж содержит `i`-тый элемент каждой из указанных последовательностей,

те на каждой итерации цикла `for` получаем `i`-тые линии из обоих файлов.

Вторую строчку объясняет [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
# python 3.6
for line1, line2 in zip(open('file1.txt'), open('file2.txt')):
    print(f'{line1.strip()}\t\t{line2.strip()}')
```

Для любого кол-ва файлов, с шириной колонки по самому длинному имени файла:

```
files = 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 
item = '{:<%s}' % (max(map(len, files)) + 5)  # мин ширина результирующей колонки
items = item * len(files) + '\n'  # шаблон для строки результата

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:  # результирующей файл
    out.write(items.format(*('#' + f for f in files)))  # имена файлов
    for lines_from_all_files in zip(*map(open, files)):  # читать построчно все файлы
        out.write(items.format(*map(str.strip, lines_from_all_files)))  # данные

# out:
# #file1.txt    #file2.txt    #file3.txt    
# 1 2           7 8           1 2           
# 3 4           9 10          3 4           
# 5 6           11 12         5 6
```

Comment: @mymedia, зачем, можно же сразу выложить рабочий код (причем с решением, как можно более непонятным для новичка), без всяких пояснений, чтобы спрашивающий ничему не научился *sarcasm*

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f:
   lines1 = f.readlines()
with open("file2.txt", 'r') as f:
   lines2 = f.readlines()
with open("out.txt", 'w') as f:
   print("{:<10s}{:<10s}".format("file1.txt", "file2.txt"))
   for linet in zip(lines1, lines2):
      print("{:<10s}{:<10s}".format(linet[0].rstrip('\n'), linet[1].rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: мне кажется, ответ будет выглядеть лучше, если добавить небольшое пояснение к коду